# Loop rows for an Excel VBA calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that copies values from three different columns in a separate worksheet. Two of the columns are strings of text, and the final column is a number that is multiplied by the integer quantity which will be a user input.

Is there a way of creating a For loop or Do loop so the code is cleaner and shorter?

```vb
Global qty As Variant


Sub PartOrder()

qty = Application.InputBox("How many assemblies are needed?")

Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
PartOrderForm.Show

End Sub


Private Sub CompleteForm_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "Part Number"
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = "Part Name"
    ActiveSheet.Range("C1") = "Number of Parts Needed"
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("B7")
    ActiveSheet.Range("B2") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("C7")
    ActiveSheet.Range("C2") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("F7") * qty
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("B8")
    ActiveSheet.Range("B3") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("C8")
    ActiveSheet.Range("C3") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("F8") * qty
    ActiveSheet.Range("A4") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("B9")
    ActiveSheet.Range("B4") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("C9")
    ActiveSheet.Range("C4") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("F9") * qty
    ActiveSheet.Range("A5") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("B10")
    ActiveSheet.Range("B5") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("C10")
    ActiveSheet.Range("C5") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("F10") * qty
    ActiveSheet.Range("A6") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("B11")
    ActiveSheet.Range("B6") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("C11")
    ActiveSheet.Range("C6") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("F11") * qty
    ActiveSheet.Range("A7") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("B12")
    ActiveSheet.Range("B7") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("C12")
    ActiveSheet.Range("C7") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("F12") * qty
    ActiveSheet.Range("A8") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("B13")
    ActiveSheet.Range("B8") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("C13")
    ActiveSheet.Range("C8") = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Range("F13") * qty

Else: End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Something like `for i=2 to 8 | cells(i,1)= | cells(i,2)= | cells(i,3)=` You only have 6 rows and 3 columns so it's not really a big deal.

Comment: `For i = 2 To 8
ActiveSheet.Cells(i - 1, 0) = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Cells(8 - i, 2)
Next i`       Is this correct? It gave me an error. Thanks for your help, as you can tell I'm still new to this @findwindow

Comment: Your error is due to there is no `0` column

Comment: @DarrellH thanks! I changed the 0 to 1 but it's saying "application-defined or object-defined error"

Answer (score 0):

You changed your code after my comment.  Loops are all about patterns.  Here is the last block of your code in a loop.  It also helps to indent your code so that you can see where your conditons and loops start and end.

```
Private Sub CompleteForm_Click()

    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "Part Number"
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = "Part Name"
        ActiveSheet.Range("C1") = "Number of Parts Needed"
    
        For x = 2 To 8
            ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1) = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Cells(x + 5, 2)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 2) = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Cells(x + 5, 3)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 3) = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Cells(x + 5, 6) * qty
        Next x

    End If

End Sub
```